# Is GL($2$,$\mathbb{Z}$) is lie group?

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

This is a very dumb question, but is $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is lie group? I don't think it is, since its underlying set don't form a manifold, but I am just not sure.

Comment: The underlying set is a manifold, just not _connected_. A point is a $0$-dimensional manifold, after all. But, no, the usual expectations of "Lie group" are _not_ met... :)  This group would normally _not_ play the _role_ of "Lie group" anywhere, even if the official definition allows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any group with at most countably many elements and the discrete topology is a zero-dimensional Lie group. So yes.

Comment: but http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_linear_group:GL(2,Z)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen $GL(n,R)$ in some contexts used to mean the group of matrices with determinant a unit in the ring $R$ (commutative).

Comment: @HaipingYang Ha this group. Ok.

Comment: @Spenser  thanks, but with euclidean topology then not, right?

Comment: @HaipingYang The standard (subspace) topology of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ as inherited from the Euclidean topology of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ *is* the discrete topology. So it is a Lie group in its natural topology.